# Moment.js-2.9.0 isSame and isAfter returns incorrect result in the same timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am implementing date range picker in jQuery using moment.js library.

I am comparing (this.endDate.isBefore(this.maxDate) || this.endDate.isSame(this.maxDate))

[image]

Comment: Do you have a code pen or js fiddle to check out the date picker?

Comment: Can you update moment to lastest version (`2.18.1`)? Note that from  version `2.10.7` moment has [`isSameOrBefore`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/) method.

Comment: I can'd upgrade it due to some dependencies..